# Mui Datepicker sets incorrect date

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, date-fns, mui-x-date-picker

I am currently using Mui Datepicker library from `@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker`.

Here's my sample code

```
     <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        inputFormat="MM/dd/yy"
        value={date}
        minDate={new Date()}
        disablePast
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          console.log("new value", newValue)
          setDate(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(props) => (
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            size="small"
            {...props}
            inputProps={{
              ...props.inputProps,
              autocomplete: 'off',
              placeholder: 'MM/DD/YY',
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Now, I would like to use `MM/dd/yy` as the date format. But when I type in 10/30/99, it returns a date 10/30/1999. I would like it to return 10/30/2099.
It is happening because the library is trying to predict the nearest year to 99 from the current date (reference date).

Is there a way to ensure I only get future dates. So in this case it returns the year 2099 instead of 1999.

I tried setting `minDate={new Date()}` and `disablePast`, but it didn't work.

codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/t8pzn7)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce this code?

Comment: Of course. @VictorL.

Comment: Could you please reproduce this error in the codesandbox? This would help me and other readers understand the problem better and find a solution faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `MM/dd/yy` as the date format, but always get a future date as the result. For example, if you type in `10/30/99`, you want to get `10/30/2099`, not `10/30/1999`.

Unfortunately, the MUI X DatePicker does not have a built-in option to do that. It uses the `date-fns` library to parse the date string. This is similar to the [`shortYearCutoff` option of jQuery DatePicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-shortYearCutoff).

According to [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/parse)

> yy will try to guess the century of two digit year by proximity with
> referenceDate:

For example:

```
console.log(parse("11/11/99", "MM/dd/yy", new Date())); // 1999-11-11
console.log(parse("11/11/73", "MM/dd/yy", new Date())); // 1973-11-11
console.log(parse("11/11/72", "MM/dd/yy", new Date())); // 2072-11-11
console.log(parse("11/11/50", "MM/dd/yy", new Date())); // 2050-11-11
console.log(parse("11/11/7", "MM/dd/yy", new Date()));  // 2007-11-11
```

One possible solution is to override `parse` method of `AdapterDateFns`.

For example:

```
class FutureDateAdapter extends AdapterDateFns {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super(props);
    this.parse = (value, formatString) => {
      if (value === null) {
        return null;
      }
      const date = new Date();
      const newDate = addYears(date, 50);
      return parse(value, formatString, newDate);
    };
  }
}
```

And then:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={FutureDateAdapter}>
  <DatePicker
    inputFormat="MM/dd/yy"
    value={date}
    onChange={setDate}
    renderInput={(props) => (
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        size="small"
        {...props}
        inputProps={{
          ...props.inputProps,
          autoComplete: "off",
          placeholder: "MM/DD/YY",
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

---

### UPDATED ANSWER

It does not handle the case when the input date is between 01/01/23 and today. In that case, it will return the past date instead of the future date.

If you want to get only the future date, you can use the `startOfDay` and `compareAsc` methods from `date-fns` instead.

For example:

```
class FutureDateAdapter extends AdapterDateFns {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super(props);
    this.parse = (value, formatString) => {
      if (value === null) {
        return null;
      }

      const newDate = new Date();
      const parsedDate = parse(value, formatString, newDate);
      const today = startOfDay(newDate);
      if (compareAsc(parsedDate, today) === -1) {
        return addYears(parsedDate, 100);
      }
      return parsedDate;
    };
  }
}
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-estrela-447r84?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Awesome ! Works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, You're welcome, I'm glad to work as expected.

Comment: Ok, there's a small issue with this. for inputs starting from 01/02/23 to today, it won't set the year as 2123. Instead if sets the past date itself. So I modified it slightly to cover that. 

      `const parsedDate = parse(value, formatString, newDate);

      if(isBefore(parsedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0), new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))){
        return addYears(parsedDate, 100)
      }

      return parsedDate;`

Comment: Thank you for your comment and feedback. I appreciate your effort to improve my solution. - @PraveenKumar. You are right, there is a small issue with my code.
Your modification is a good way to fix that issue. However, I noticed that your code uses `setHours` and `isBefore` methods, which are not part of `date-fns` library. They are part of JavaScript Date object. This may cause some confusion or inconsistency when using `AdapterDateFns`, which is supposed to use `date-fns` methods only. So I updated my answer. Please check it.